# Is it possible to perform CPA attack against CBC changing IV by last ciphertext block?

Tags: cbc, chosen-plaintext-attack

I was trying to do a simple CPA attack against this scheme, to understand better the concept.

Instead of using a new  each time, we decide to use the last block
of the previous ciphertext as an initialization vector. Prove this new scheme is vulnerable to a
chosen-plaintext attack.

So in this case,

- the challenger chooses a "game" and a key.
- After that, we send $(0\ldots 0,1\ldots 1)$
- and we receive $(IV, c)$.
- Now we send $(0\ldots 0, 0\ldots 0)$
- and we receive $(IV'=c , c')$.
- So if $c$ is equal to $IV'$ then the challenger is playing the left game, right otherwise.

Am I right? Am I confusing the concepts? When we talk about a block, is all the cipher or only the last bit?

Comment: This game is problematic since the first IV generation is not clear. Anyway, assuming that is random for the first time, you need to send $(1\ldots 1)$ as the first data on the second try. Write CBC equations and see better? ( note that you seem to send two blocks)

Comment: I don't really see a connection to guess the game. The first time I send the message, I will recive (IV, F(k,mi xor ci-1)), second time ( F(k,mi xor ci-1), F(k,mi' xor ci-1')). I guess I'm missing something required to solve the attack.

Comment: maybe I just get it, if I do  the cipher of the second try XOR with the IV of the first try, I will get the message of the second try?

Comment: Send $((c \oplus IV), (1\ldots 1)$ on the second time?

Comment: If this is not homework can you write an answer to your question?

Comment: Let's assume that I'm playing "left game", so in this case if in the first try I do (0..0,0..0) and in the second try (c⊕IV),(1…1), then if both cipher are equals, then left game, otherwise right?

Comment: Yes, no problem, after solve it, I upload the answer

Comment: Note: here CPA stands for Choosen Plaintext Attacks (not Correlation Power Analysis). Hint: in standard CBC, can the plaintext be chosen with knowledge of the IV? What about that modified CBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attack goes as follows, first the adversary asks for the encryption $(0…0,0…0)$. Then he gets $c_1=(c_{11},c_{12})=(IV,F_{K}(m_{\gamma_1}\oplus IV))=(IV,c=F_{K}(IV))$, since $m_{\gamma_1}=0…0$ regardless of the value of $\gamma$.  Then he asks for the encryption of $(m_{L_2}=0…0,m_{R_2}=c_{12}\oplus IV)$, and gets  $c_2=(c_{21},c_{22})=(F_{K}(IV),F_{K}(F_{K}(IV)\oplus m_{\gamma_2}))$. If $\gamma=L$, he gets $(F_{K}(IV),F_{K}(F_{K}(IV))$ and if $\gamma=R$ he gets $(F_{K}(IV),F_{K}(F_{K}(IV)\oplus c_{12}\oplus IV)=(F_{K}(IV),F_{K}(IV))$ since $c_{12}=F_{K}(IV)$.  In summary if $c_{21}=c_{22}$ he says $\gamma=R$ and he says $\gamma=L$ otherwise.